# "slc loopback" doesn't create "common" directory

Tags: json, command-line-interface, loopback

I can't find user, acl and such json files because the tool isn't creating "common" directory where these belong.

This is what I get with slc --version:

```
├── strong-arc@1.8.4 (b7b568d)
├── strong-build@2.0.6 (d008a3e)
├── strong-deploy@3.1.2 (be6180a)
├── strong-mesh-models@8.1.0 (62e539b)
├── strong-pm@5.0.1 (b96f806)
├── strong-registry@1.1.5 (f46e58f)
├── strong-start@1.3.2 (1327018)
├─┬ strong-supervisor@3.3.1 (1e39220)
│ └── strong-agent@2.0.2 (4ea7ee9)
├── generator-loopback@1.13.0 (a884c0b)
├── node-inspector@0.7.4
└── nodefly-register@0.3.3
```

And this is the package.json file that "slc loopback" generates:

```
{
  "name": "asd",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "server/server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "pretest": "jshint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "compression": "^1.0.3",
    "cors": "^2.5.2",
    "loopback": "^2.22.0",
    "loopback-boot": "^2.6.5",
    "loopback-component-explorer": "^2.1.0",
    "loopback-datasource-juggler": "^2.39.0",
    "serve-favicon": "^2.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "jshint": "^2.5.6"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "",
    "url": ""
  },
  "description": "asd"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loopback will generate the needed `json` and `js` files once you start creating your own models and ACLs. which happens that it creates the `common` directory

running the following command:

```
slc loopback:model
```

will allow you to extend the `User` model and then you will be able to add the proper `ACL` permissions through:

```
slc loopback:acl
```